# How to copy the entire content of a text file and mail it using java mail API?

Tags: java, log4j, jakarta-mail

[image]I have a Log File log.txt and it is being generated by log4j
Now I need to copy the Entire content of the log file and send the copied data as an Email.

below are my codes:
Lo4j Properties:

```
#Log to Console as STDOUT
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} \
%-5p %c %3x - %m%n
#Log to file FILE
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\logfile.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'dd/MM/yyyy
log4j.appender.file.append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern= %m%n
# LOG4J daily rolling log files configuration
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, RollingAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=D:\logfile.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %m%n
#CONFIGURE SMTP
log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.email.SMTPHost=smtp.gmail.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPUsername=ilavarasan.mbsjgr@gmail.com
log4j.appender.email.SMTPPassword=Flower@123
log4j.appender.email.From=ilavarasan.mbsjgr@gmail.com
log4j.appender.email.To=ilavarasan.mtss@gmail.com
log4j.appender.email.Subject=Log of messages
log4j.appender.email.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.email.EvaluatorClass=TriggerLogEvent
log4j.appender.email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.email.layout.ConversionPattern=%m
# INFO level will be logged
log4j.logger.comparexmlf1.mailer1 = INFO, email
# turn off additivity
log4j.logger.comparexmlf1.mailer1 = false
```

### a piece of java code for Mail :

---

```
MimeMessage message = new 
MimeMessage(session);                                   
m_toterr=validatexml.Total_err;
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));   
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to1));
message.setSubject("RE : CAR Validation Report at :
"+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())); 
message.addHeaderLine("line");
MimeHeader header1=new MimeHeader("Content-Type","test/html");
line10.setContent(htmlBody,"text/html");
message.setContent(htmlBody, "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

A piece of java code for Log4j SMTP Appender

```
public class Mailer1 {
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Mailer1.class);

public void logMail(String mailString) {
logger.info(mailString);
}
}
```

Tried both my own app to send the mail and used log4j appender.But both not copying the log file and not throwing the emails.

Can any one help me on this? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to get the `FileAppender` from your log4j configuration

```
String pathLogFile = "";
Enumeration enumeration = Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders();
while ( enumeration.hasMoreElements() ){
   Appender appender = (Appender) e.nextElement();
   if ( appender instanceof FileAppender ){
      pathLogFile  = ((FileAppender)appender).getFile(); //here you get the path
      break;
   }
}
```

Now that you got the path for your log file, read all lines:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(pathLogFile);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

String singleLine;
while ((singleLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(singleLine + "\n");
}
br.close();
String allLines = sb.toString();
```

And then compose the mail with the content of the file:

```
message.setContent(allLines);
```

Update (get only lines that begin with...):

```
String singleLine;
while ((singleLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
  if(singleLine.startsWith("Err :")) {
    sb.append(singleLine + "<br>");
  }
}
```

Comment: but it throws a compile time error as : Multiple markers at this line
 - The method getPath() is undefined for the 
  type String
 - Line breakpoint:mailer [line: 55] - sendmail()
 - The method getPath() is undefined for the 
  type String

Comment: at line :
  pathLogFile  = ((FileAppender)appender).getFile().getPath()

Comment: I dont need it to be sent as attachment but i need to end the content as email body.Kindly help accordingly.

Comment: @IlavarasanJayaraman don't forget to mark this answer as the correct one by clicking the check mark on the left side

Comment: Kindly help me to get the email as formatted in my error logger.

Comment: just replace the "\n" with this "<br>"

Comment: Can you please guide me how to get the lines starts with the text : Err from the file and mail it.
(My exact requirement is to throw the error logger mail.But my Logfile Contents unwanted data for log mail.)

Comment: look at the edit. By the way you should really learn what it's appening in the code I wrote and check the Java Documentation

Comment: How to avoid getting the lines and storing in to the variable stringLine ,which are all already been read and stored in to the stringLine?.So that I can Avoid printing the duplicate data in mail.pls help.

Comment: use a `LinkedHashSet<String>`. [Read this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to know to use it

Comment: Kindly help me with a piece of code as above explained by you.