# how to read lines start with string : Err from a text file and mail it to the recipients using JAVA

Tags: java, email, error-logging

1. I have an *error log* text file
2. Now I would like to read all the lines start with the text `Err` ,and store it in to a `String Array` using `Java`
3. Mail the content of the `String array` read

My piece of JAVA code:

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session); 
String pathLogFile = "D:/logfile.log";
Enumeration enumeration =    
CarParser1.logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders();
            while ( enumeration.hasMoreElements() ){
               Appender appender = (Appender) enumeration.nextElement();
               if ( appender instanceof FileAppender ){
                  pathLogFile  = ((FileAppender)appender).getFile();    
//here you get the path
                  break;
               }
            }
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(pathLogFile);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(fstream));

            String singleLine;
            while ((singleLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
              sb.append(singleLine + "<br>");
            }
            br.close();
            String allLines = sb.toString();
     message.setContent(allLines, "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
     Transport.send(message);
    System.out.println("Email Sent successfully....");
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: you didn't mention the issues that you face with above code or where you stuck?

Comment: It copies all the content of my text file.
but i need the lines start with err .also there will be a string as "Execution Date & Time :27/01/2016 14:32:31".

Comment: The time date and time should be very nearest to the current date and current time.Then That also need to store in the variable

Comment: Then I have to mail these.please help

Comment: move all these comments to your question section to list your question properly, even though your question has already been answered & it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are reading everything from the LogFile and sending it in the mail body. You just have to add an additional condition in your for loop to filter out the messages starting with "Err"

```
String singleLine;
while ((singleLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
     if(singleLine.startsWith("Err")) //Filter Condition
          sb.append(singleLine + "<br>");
}
```

You can also use `contains("Err")` etc. depending on what filter you want.

Comment: I'm glad that it works for you. If you are happy then please accept the answer and help us close the question.

Comment: How to avoid reading and storing the lines to the variable singleLine , which are all already been read and stored in to that variable.?
Kindly help sir

Comment: So that I can Avoid getting the Duplicate data which is being stored in that variable.

Comment: You are not reading any duplicate data. `singleLine = br.readLine()` singleLine will always have the next line present in the Log File until it reaches the end of the file.

Comment: Actually the source text file is a log file and it is being updated.
when ever i execute the program it is getting the old log details also.so i just wanted to avoid those unwanted data.please guide me to achieve this.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the program. It is reading the Log File. If your Log File is having the old data then it will read that too. You should probably fix your Logging Strategy to keep only new Logs. Hint: Look at Log4j's `RollingFileAppender` where you can specify the Log Size/Backup Index. Alternatively, you can manually archive the old Log Files so that only fresh Logs are present in the file.

Comment: Also, I think the original question about reading the lines is answered. You should probably search/raise a new question for Logging related queries.

Comment: @user2004685 give up on him, we are doing his homework! [Look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942481/how-to-copy-the-entire-content-of-a-text-file-and-mail-it-using-java-mail-api/34942874#34942874). He also take off my accept answer because I stopped help him with new questions in comments...